# Repeat a Calculation for Each item in a Dataframe list and name it uniquely

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code to give Signals (1 or 0)

The issue is I have a List of stocks close price ['SPY','TLT',.... etc]
What I am doing now is changing the stock = df[] manually for each stock.

Can you advise how to create a function for this please?
Also df['Signal'] should be unique for each.. for example df['SPY'] will produce df['SPYsignal']

I am too new to python and have tried with errors, hopefully you can guide me thanks.

```
# I am doing this for all my tickers, this is inefficient 
# Only wanted to do it for selected columns so I should begin with List = [['SPY','TLT']] yes? 

stock = df['SPY']

df['avg'] = stock.shift(1).rolling(window=5).mean()
df['LongEntry'] = stock > df.avg
df['LongExit'] = stock < df.avg

df['PositionLong'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.LongEntry,'PositionLong'] = 1
df.loc[df.LongExit, 'PositionLong'] = 0

df['SPYSignal'] = df.PositionLong 
df['SPYSignal'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['SPYSignal'].fillna(0, inplace = True)

print (df['SPYSignal'])


stock = df['TLT']

df['avg'] = stock.shift(1).rolling(window=5).mean()
df['LongEntry'] = stock > df.avg
df['LongExit'] = stock < df.avg

df['PositionLong'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.LongEntry,'PositionLong'] = 1
df.loc[df.LongExit, 'PositionLong'] = 0

df['TLTSignal'] = df.PositionLong 
df['TLTSignal'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['TLTSignal'].fillna(0, inplace = True)

print (df['TLTSignal'])
```

Dataframe Sample

```
SPY TLT
100 200
102 202
105 208
106 205
108 210
```

Desired Output

```
SPY TLT SPYSignal   TLTSignal
100 200      0          1
102 202      1          0
105 208      0          0
106 205      1          0
108 210      0          1
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the df and the desired output?

Comment: Have added the Sample and desired output thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
for stockClosePrice in ['SPY','TLT', 'OTHERVALUES']:
    stock = df[stockClosePrice]

    df['avg'] = stock.shift(1).rolling(window=5).mean()
    df['LongEntry'] = stock > df.avg
    df['LongExit'] = stock < df.avg

    df['PositionLong'] = np.nan
    df.loc[df.LongEntry,'PositionLong'] = 1
    df.loc[df.LongExit, 'PositionLong'] = 0

    stockSignal = stockClosePrice + 'Signal'

    df[stockSignal] = df.PositionLong 
    df[stockSignal].fillna(method='ffill')
    df[stockSignal].fillna(0, inplace = True)

    print (df[stockSignal])
```

This code loops through every `'SPY', 'TLT', ...` strings and processes them as you were doing manually before.

I hope I've got your question right!

Comment: Yes great this is right... thanks Daniele, you taught me how to use a function (This is called a function yes?)

Comment: No, it isn't. It is just a for loop (an execution flow controller, called iterator). There is no specific need to use a function here!